# Incorrect Hue returned by getHue function

Tags: objective-c, ios4, colors, rgb

I am converting RGB to HSV using built in function of UIColour: `- (BOOL)getHue:(CGFloat *)hue saturation:(CGFloat *)saturation brightness:(CGFloat *)brightness alpha:(CGFloat *)alpha` but for some RGB it is not giving correct output.

```
CGFloat h,s,v,a;
UIColor *tColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(230.0/255.0) green:(226.0/255.0) blue:(226.0/255.0) alpha:1.0];
BOOL success=[tColor getHue:&h saturation:&s brightness:&v alpha:&a];
NSLog(@"Output-> Success:%d, hue:%f, sat:%f, value:%f, alpha:%f",success,h,s,v,a);
```

**Actual output:**
Output-> Success:1, hue:1.000000, sat:0.017391, value:0.901961, alpha:1.000000

**Expected output:**
hue:0, sat:0.017391, value:0.901961, alpha:1.000000

Note: I have derived this expected output from some online conversion tools(ex: http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/rgb-to-hsv.htm)

You can see clearly difference in Hue? So, why such difference in Hue and how can I get my expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hue in HSB or HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_color_space#Basic_principle) is measured as degrees around a colour circle, starting with red at 0° and wrapping back around to red at 360°; so a hue of 0° is the same as a hue of 360°. `UIColor` maps this range (0–360°) to the values 0–1 (0°=0.0, 360°=1.0).

Comment: You told 360°=1.0. function giving me hue:1.0 in actual output so in degree it will be 360 but my expected output is 0 not 360

Comment: I am agree your provided information is correct but you also not included how to convert my actual output to desired output

Comment: As 一二三 explained, 1.0 = 360° is equivalent to 0.0 = 0°. To normalize your hue to the range 0.0 <= hue < 1.0 just use `hue = fmodf(hue, 1.0)`.

Comment: Your "expected output" and "actual output" are the same colour, nothing needs to be converted.

Comment: If you are doing math with hues, normalizing is crucial. So thanks for `fmodf` tip, @MartinR.

Answer (score 4):

While most of the rest of the world defines "hue" as going from 0 to 360 degrees, for UIColor it's 0.0 to 1.0.

Actually, just as 360.000 degrees is identical to 0.000 in geometry or someone else's hue, so we have with UIColor's hue that 1.000 is identical to 0.000  (hallucinate as many zero digits after the decimal point as you like, and in binary if you prefer.)

So, your "actual output" and "expected output" are identical.  In coding, keep hue in the range 0.000 to 0.999, and change 1.000 to 0.000 to avoid trouble.